# Youtube embedded player: Event when video has ended

Tags: c#, winforms, youtube-api

I'm creating an application which plays youtube videos in C# (winform). Now i'd like to fire an event, or something like that, when the video has ended.
I'm using the webbrowser control and call a youtube video like this:

```
wbYoutube.Navigate("http://www.youtube.com/v/" + playString[1] + "?version=3&enablejsapi=1&autoplay=1");
```

playString[1] is the youtube video id (like rGJN5K2cV_8).

I've been trying to get this working a few days now, has anyone got an idea on how to achieve this? If it's even possible...

If you need more info, let me know.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is possible but you have to write the html code into the browser element by yourself

```
wbYoutube.DocumentText = "";
```

Here is the html (You have to escape it)

```
    <html><head></head><body>

    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.youtube.com/player_api'></script>
    <iframe id="player" width="100%" height="100%" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEO_ID?autoplay=1&controls=0&enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var player;
    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
            videoId: 'VIDEO_ID',
            events: {
                'onStateChange': function(evt){
                    if(evt.data == 0){
                        window.external.Test('Video finished!!');
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
    </script>

</body></html>
```

And have a look at [Implement Two-Way Communication Between DHTML Code and Client Application Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a0746166.aspx)

There you find the rest of the code.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm having trouble getting this to work. Do i have to use youtube.com/embed or can i also use youtube.com/v? for some reason when i use embed instead of v the controls in the player don't appear... edit: the function is working, it seems the javascript part is not working yet

Comment: You have to use the "embed" url. To enable the controls change the parameter `&controls=1` `http://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEO_ID?autoplay=1&controls=1&enablejsapi=1`. Which javascript part is not working? More info on this api [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference)

Comment: i already tried the controls parameter but it didn't change anything. I'll try some things again tomorrow. Too bad i have to use an iframe because now some video's won't play..

Comment: You don't have to use the iframe api. You also can use the javascript api. The cool thing about the iframe api is that it deliver html5 video if the browser does not support flash. Read about the javascript api [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference).